# ASP.net text file download generation

Tags: asp.net

I tried to look this up all over the place, but none of the examples given online helps me.

I basically want a button on an ASP.net page to generate some text in memory, and when the user clicks on it, display a download dialog for a user to download a text file with the generated text.

The code I have currently is:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=cartune.csv");

string text = "hello";

Response.Write(text);
Response.End();
```

But it doesn't work in Firefox 3.5 nor IE 8.0, I get no download response from the browsers at all... Many examples given online are similar to the code I have, so can any experts please point out to me what I am doing wrong?

I am running debugging mode in the Visual Studio 2008 deubugger, not IIS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=filename.csv");
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.Write("hello");
    Response.End();
```

Works for me in Firefox 3.5.  I just wrote this for my own project today.